# Gratis alternative to MailSuite Pro for linux

Tags: gratis, email, centos-7, email-server

I'm looking for an alternative to [AfterLogic's MailSuite Pro for Linux](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailsuite/linux-email-server) application. This application is exactly what I looking for with the one exception of not being gratis. I'm looking for a mail server application that has the following requirements,

- Gratis
- Runs on CentOS 7
- Has an install wizard that is somewhat easy to use
- Being updated frequently
- Easy to use (both the administration end and the user/client end)
- SMTP/ESMTP server
- POP3 server
- IMAP server
- online webmail client (like roundcude)
- Supports multiple domains and accounts
- Forwarder accounts
- Web admin panel
- Can set disk quotas for users
- Can set # of emails to be sent per hour (or some time interval or alternative feature)

Comment: I'd recommend looking at ISPConfig.  No install wizzard, but a great set of directions that even my first semester linux students can follow.